# Flash plugin which allows image upload from clipboard to server

Tags: flash, image, upload, clipboard

I want to embed a flash to my site, that allows the user to paste an image which is in clipboard, and this images will then be uploaded to the server.

Is there a script that can do that?
i googled for about an hour now, but didn't find anything that fits my needs.

the best thing would be if you also coul crop your image when its uploaded and then save it.

it's most likely to upload screenshots, so that you don't have to first save it, crop it, and then upload it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, due to security reasons. [This](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html#setClipboard()) clearly states the concept. However you can do it in AIR application.